# Well defined narrowing cast

Tags: c++, casting

I'm trying to come up with a narrowing cast (a general solution) that gracefully ignores lost data. In Visual Studio, a narrowing cast that loses data triggers a "Run-Time Check Failure #1". I do not want to turn it off, instead I'm trying to implement a `narrow_cast` that would gracefully do narrowing casts and wouldn't trigger the run time check.

Visual Studio suggests:

```
char c = (i & 0xFF);
```

So I started with this, and came up with this ugly solution:

```
template< typename T >
struct narrow_mask
{
  static const T value = T(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF);
};

template <typename T, typename U>
T narrow_cast(const U& a)
{
  return static_cast<T>(a & narrow_mask<T>::value );
}
```

While it works (VS it seems is perfectly fine with losing data on constants), it's neither complete (no support for non integral data), nor correct (I think it would not work correctly for signed values).

Any suggestions for a better solution, or a better narrow_mask implementation?

**Edit:** In face of comments that this question is VS specific, I checked the standard document, and it seems that the result of a narrowing `static_cast` is implementation dependant. Hence, the question can be nicer stated as creating a well-defined (ergo, not implementation dependant) narrowing cast. I do not care much about the specifics of the result value, as long as it's well defined and dependant on the type (not `return 0`).

Comment: If nothing else, you could use template specialization for non-integral types, but that does seem kinda hackish.

Comment: Well, you could do a bit of template meta-programming and use [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) to build the mask and preform checks and stuff

Comment: I thought about that, but that would still not work for non-integrals.

Comment: Does your compiler warn if you make a `static_cast`? At least gcc does not complain if the narrowing conversion is explicit: `int i = f(); short s = i;` warns, but `short s = static_cast<short>(i);` does not warn --you told it that you *know* what you are doing by means of the cast

Comment: It doesn't warn. Worse, it does a debugger break, but only if information is lost (ergo the larger type contains more than the smaller type holds). This is usually useful, but sometimes we want to explicitly tell him "Ok, I know what I'm doing"

Comment: Hmm, and there I thought that `reinterpret_cast` is what you do when you want to tell the compiler "I really mean it." Doesn't that work?

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` requires the types to be the same size.

Comment: This question is tagged as c++, but this check of Visual Studio is intentionally incompatible with the C++ standard, as I understand it. The C++ answer would be "use a C++ compiler", though I doubt that is of any real help to you.

Comment: The question was intentionally not tagged with VS, because I'm trying to come up with a solution that is fully C++ compliant, preferably by creating a proper `&` mask, or finding an alternative way to perform a narrowing cast. The solution must work for all compilers.

Comment: BTW, the result of a `static_cast` when narrowing is implementation dependent, so we can totally put VS out of the question, and ask how to perform a well-formed narrowing cast. So "use a C++ complier" is not an answer :)

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz The standard doesn't require a specific result when converting to a narrower signed type, but it does require a result. And a narrowing conversion to an unsigned type is well-defined. In standard C++, you could portably convert any integer number to a narrower unsigned type. In not-100%-standard-but-still-portable C++, you could then convert that to the corresponding signed type, if needed.

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz What do you want as a result for values greater than numeric maximum of the target type? e.g. `narrow_cast<int8_t>(0xFF)` (as far as I understand the Standard, the bitwise `&` is not a problem)

Comment: Here is a related question that I asked, with an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4424168/509868

Comment: May the downvoter state his reasons?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one version that uses a little bit of C++11. If you don't have access to `constexpr`, you can just delete it. If you don't have access to `std::make_unsigned`, it's possible to implement your own. If you don't have `std::enable_if`, you might be able to use Boost's (or make your own). It works for both signed and unsigned types, as well as positive and negative values. **Update**: updated to work with floating point types (and floating point to integral, and vice versa).

```
#include <type_traits>

// From integer type to integer type
template <typename to, typename from>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<from>::value && std::is_integral<to>::value, to>::type
narrow_cast(const from& value)
{
    return static_cast<to>(value & (static_cast<typename std::make_unsigned<from>::type>(-1)));
}

// For these next 3 versions, you'd be best off locally disabling the compiler warning
// There isn't much magic you can do when floating point types get invovled

// From floating point type to floating point type
template <typename to, typename from>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<from>::value && std::is_floating_point<to>::value, to>::type
narrow_cast(const from& value)
{
    // The best you can do here is a direct cast
    return static_cast<to>(value);
}

// From integer type to floating point type
template <typename to, typename from>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<from>::value && std::is_floating_point<to>::value, to>::type
narrow_cast(const from& value)
{
    // The best you can do here is a direct cast
    return static_cast<to>(value);
}

// From floating point type to integer type
template <typename to, typename from>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<from>::value && std::is_integral<to>::value, to>::type
narrow_cast(const from& value)
{
    // The best you can do here is a direct cast
    return static_cast<to>(value);
}
```

Comment: +1 : I'll award the bounty to Potatoswatter because he's got the highest upvote count, but I'm really grateful for this answer because I'm working in a C++11 setup, and think that  this approach has it's benefits.

Comment: Is std::make_unsigned<from>(-1) correct? I would expect std::make_unsigned<to>(-1), based on the example implementation in the question and my own intuition of what makes the default narrowing behaviour implementation-defined.

Answer (score 7):

Use `std::numeric_limits` and the modulus operator. Get the maximum allowed value of the destination type, cast it to the source type, add one, take the modulus, and cast to the destination type.

The resulting value will certainly be representable in the destination type, i.e. there will be no undefined behavior, but I don't know if MSVC will still throw a warning. I don't have a copy of it to check.

This doesn't preserve negative numbers, though. It can probably be extended to do so, but I'm not sure how. (It's getting late here.)

```
template< typename to, typename from >
to narrow_cast( from value ) {
    static_assert( std::numeric_limits< to >::max() < std::numeric_limits< from >::max(),
        "narrow_cast used in non-narrowing context" );

    return static_cast< to >( from %
        ( static_cast< from >( std::numeric_limits< to >::max() ) + 1 ) ) );
}
```

Comment: There are a couple of issues, but yeah, this seems workable... however, this will generate suboptimal code compared to the & solution which gets optimized off?

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz: There's a good chance the compiler will be able to optimize it. For example, if casting to an `unsigned char`, `max() + 1` should yield 256 (on most systems), and the compiler should know how to optimize `% 256` very well.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to restrict myself to free operations. The modulus should translate to a bitwise AND which in turn should be implemented as access to the low-order part of a register. What's missing is sign extension. Actually the whole wrap-around policy should be explicit, and perhaps should not be allowed for negative numbers. I might expand this later.

Comment: Your `static_assert` is too restrictive: `int` is ranked below `long`, but there are a good many implementations where they have the same range.

Comment: @Deduplicator It is quite restrictive, but it's appropriate for the given message.

Answer (score 1):

Bjarne's TCPPPL comes up with some kind of narrow cast which does a runtime check to see if some conversion loses information. Taken textually from Section 11.5 :

```
template<class Target, class Source>
Target narrow_cast(Source v)
{
    auto r = static_cast<Target>(v);
    if (static_cast<Source>(r) != v)
        throw runtime_error("narrow_cast<>() failed");
    return r;
}
```

The basic idea is to check if the backward conversion gives back the original value; then we should be satisfied since there was no lost information. This version works fine with integral/integral conversions since they are all well defined (narrowing to signed types must be well defined by the implementation, raising an exception would be non conforming). Although, you should probably refine this definition with other overloads and put some SFINAE since this code could lead to UB in the cases of floating/floating and integral/floating conversions when the target type is too small, even for unsigned types.

Answer (score -2):

Piece of cake!

In this example, let's take a pointer (64 bits in my machine) and "transform it" into a single Byte:

```
char narrowme (char *p) {

    union {
        char *p;
        char c[8];
    } x;

    x.p = p;

    return x.c[0];  // pick the byte you want!
}
```

To use, simply call it; for instance,    c = narrowme (&c2);

You may use a #define if you wish. Anyway, there will always be code involved.

Comment: Pretty sure this is only well-defined in C. My understanding is that in C++, it's UB to write to one union field and then read from a different one.

Comment: Endian issues arise.  Was `x.c[0]` the LSByte or MSByte of the pointer?