# What float values could not be converted to int without undefined behavior [c++]?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++14, implicit-conversion

I just read this from the C++14 standard (my emphasis):

> **4.9 Floating-integral conversions [conv.fpint]**
>
> **1** A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. *The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be
> represented in the destination type.* *[...]*

Which got me thinking

1. Which, if any, `float` values could not be represented as `int` after truncation? (Does that depend on the implementation?)
2. If there are any, does this mean that `auto x = static_cast<int>(float)` is unsafe?
3. what is the proper/safe way of converting `float` to `int` then (assuming you want truncation)?

Comment: Conciser the maximum magnitude of floats vs ints. See __Range of values__ in: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types  (3) see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/climits

Comment: Also, I'd bet on `NaN`. `NaN` is always the weird one.

Comment: `auto x = static_cast<int>(f);` is just an obscure way of writing `int x = f;`. Neither is more or less safe than the other, regardless of how you define "safe".

Comment: @PeteBecker I wouldn't call `static_cast` obscure. It's actually quite explicit that the cast is intended whereas in the case of `int x = f;`it's anyone's guess rather it's an intended implicit cast or a mistake.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux -- I didn't say that `static_cast` is obscure. I said that the **statement** is obscure; there's more in it than the `static_cast`.

Comment: See [this blog post](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2017/06/19/sometimes-floating-point-math-is-perfect/)

Comment: @PeteBecker `static_cast` is the correct way to do it; most compilers support and many (most?) companies use warnings that will flag `int x = f`.

Comment: @NirFriedman -- my company doesn't. Labelling "the way I prefer to do it" as "the correct way to do it" is inappropriate.

Comment: @PeteBecker Congrats, some companies don't use -Werror either. Point? There are recognized good practices. Flagging narrowing conversions are widely (but not universally) recognized as a good practice.

Comment: Sounds like you mean "to an integer-valued float". Because there's no "proper way" to make an `int` whose value cannot be represented by `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't be surprising at all that `float` has values outside of `int` range. Floating-point values were invented to represent very large (and also very small) values adequately.

1. `INT_MAX + 1` (usually equal to `2147483648`) cannot be represented by `int`, but can be represented by `float`.
2. Yes, `static_cast<int>(float)` is as unsafe as undefined behavior can be. However, something as simple as `x + y` for sufficiently large integers `x` and `y` is also UB, so no big surprise here either.
3. The proper way to do stuff depends on the application, as always in C++. Boost has `numeric_cast` that throws an exception on overflow; this might be good for you. To do saturation (convert too big values to `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`), write some code like this

   ```
   float f;
   int i;
   ...
   if (static_cast<double>(INT_MIN) <= f && f < static_cast<double>(INT_MAX))
       i = static_cast<int>(f);
   else if (f < 0)
       i = INT_MIN;
   else
       i = INT_MAX;
   ```

   However, this is not ideal. Does your system have `double` type that can represent the maximal value of `int`? If yes, it will work. Also, how exactly do you want to round values that are close to minimum or maximum of `int`? If you don't want to consider such questions, use `boost::numeric_cast`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4424208/509868).

Comment: I was perhaps not clear enough with "proper/safe what" in point 3. I should have added something like "assuming you want to keep to the truncation" (see edit).

Comment: Yes this works for common implementations, but fails when `int` and `float` are wide, like 64-bit.  True that OP's alludes to that limitation.

Answer (score 8):

We hit this a while back and I manually made some tables that have the exact bit patterns of floats at the edges of various conversions to various sizes of integers. Note this assumes iee754 4 byte `floats` and 8 bytes `doubles` and 2's complement signed integers (`int32_t` of 4 bytes and `int64_t` of 8 bytes).

If you need to convert the bit patterns to floats or doubles you'll need to either type pun them (technically UB) or `memcpy` them.

And to answer your question anything which is too big to fit in the target integer is UB on conversion, and the only time when the truncating to zero matters is `double` -> `int32_t`. So using the following values you can compare the float against the relevant min/max and only cast if they're in range.

Note that using `INT_MIN`/`INT_MAX` (or their modern limit counterparts) to cross convert and then compare doesn't always work as the accuracy of floats for those sized values are very low.

Inf/NaN are also UB on conversion.

```
// float->int64 edgecases
static const uint32_t FloatbitsMaxFitInt64 = 0x5effffff; // [9223371487098961920] Largest float which still fits int an signed int64
static const uint32_t FloatbitsMinNofitInt64 = 0x5f000000; // [9223372036854775808] the bit pattern of the smallest float which is too big for a signed int64
static const uint32_t FloatbitsMinFitInt64 = 0xdf000000; // [-9223372036854775808] Smallest float which still fits int an signed int64
static const uint32_t FloatbitsMaxNotfitInt64 = 0xdf000001; // [-9223373136366403584] Largest float which to small for a signed int64

// float->int32 edgecases
static const uint32_t FloatbitsMaxFitInt32 = 0x4effffff; // [2147483520] the bit pattern of the largest float which still fits int an signed int32
static const uint32_t FloatbitsMinNofitInt32 = 0x4f000000; // [2147483648] the bit pattern of the smallest float which is too big for a signed int32
static const uint32_t FloatbitsMinFitInt32 = 0xcf000000; // [-2147483648] the bit pattern of the smallest float which still fits int an signed int32
static const uint32_t FloatbitsMaxNotfitInt32 = 0xcf000001; // [-2147483904] the bit pattern of the largest float which to small for a signed int32

// double->int64 edgecases
static const uint64_t DoubleBitsMaxFitInt64 = 0x43dfffffffffffff; // [9223372036854774784] Largest double which fits into an int64
static const uint64_t DoubleBitsMinNofitInt64 = 0x43e0000000000000; // [9223372036854775808] Smallest double which is too big for an int64
static const uint64_t DoubleBitsMinFitInt64 = 0xc3e0000000000000; // [-9223372036854775808] Smallest double which fits into an int64
static const uint64_t DoubleBitsMaxNotfitInt64 = 0xc3e0000000000001; // [-9223372036854777856] largest double which is too small to fit into an int64

// double->int32 edgecases[when truncating(round towards zero)]
static const uint64_t DoubleBitsMaxTruncFitInt32 = 0x41dfffffffffffff; // [~2147483647.9999998] Largest double that when truncated will fit into an int32
static const uint64_t DoubleBitsMinTruncNofitInt32 = 0x41e0000000000000; // [2147483648.0000000] Smallest double that when truncated wont fit into an int32
static const uint64_t DoubleBitsMinTruncFitInt32 = 0xc1e00000001fffff; // [~2147483648.9999995] Smallest double that when truncated will fit into an int32
static const uint64_t DoubleBitsMaxTruncNofitInt32 = 0xc1e0000000200000; // [2147483649.0000000] Largest double that when truncated wont fit into an int32

// double->int32 edgecases [when rounding via bankers method(round to nearest, round to even on half)]
static const uint64_t DoubleBitsMaxRoundFitInt32 = 0x41dfffffffdfffff; // [2147483647.5000000] Largest double that when rounded will fit into an int32
static const uint64_t DoubleBitsMinRoundNofitInt32 = 0x41dfffffffe00000; // [~2147483647.5000002] Smallest double that when rounded wont fit into an int32
static const uint64_t DoubleBitsMinRoundFitInt32 = 0xc1e0000000100000; // [-2147483648.5000000] Smallest double that when rounded will fit into an int32
static const uint64_t DoubleBitsMaxRoundNofitInt32 = 0xc1e0000000100001; // [~2147483648.5000005] Largest double that when rounded wont fit into an int32
```

So for your example you want:

```
if( f >= B2F(FloatbitsMinFitInt32) && f <= B2F(FloatbitsMaxFitInt32))
    // cast is valid.
```

Where B2F is something like:

```
float B2F(uint32_t bits)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(uint32_t), "Weird arch");
    float f;
    memcpy(&f, &bits, sizeof(float));
    return f;
}
```

Note that this conversion picks up nans/inf correctly (as comparisons with them are false) *unless* you're using a non-iee754 mode of your compiler (e.g. ffast-math on gcc or /fp:fast on msvc)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you clarify what you meant with the bit about "when the truncating to zero matters" and the part about comparing to INT_MIN/INT_MAX?

Comment: The range of float when its got a close value to INT_MAX is something like 1 float every 150 numbers. So it hasn't got a fractional part for numbers of that magnitude. (But doubles with values close to them do). INT_MIN and INT_MAX cannot be represented by floats so casting INT_MIN to a float is lossy and therefore any calculation you do with it will have an error. And you must be exact to not give UB.

Comment: OK, and what do you mean by "the only time when the truncating to zero matters is float -> int64_t"?

Comment: EDIT: I meant double -> int32!. For INT_MAX (~2147483647) the 2 closest floats are 2147483520 below it and 2147483648 above it. There's simply no floating point representation of 2147483647.xxx where truncation matters. For double -> int32 there are double values with things like 2147483647.99 and so as the standard says to truncate this means that 2147483647.99 WILL fit into an int32.

Comment: OK, great. Very insightful answer, even if it assumes particular representations

Comment: @ricab I thought a wile about this and it seemed really hard to get better than this. The language really doesn't make it easy to do this in a portable way.

Comment: Right, and so your answer is very valuable, but I suppose I would rather offload that to `boost::numeric_cast` as suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Which, if any, float values could not be represented as int after truncation?

After the `float` value is truncated, the whole number value must be in the `INT` range `[INT_MIN ... INT_MAX]`.  If outside this range, or not-a-number, conversion is UB.

> 2. If there are any, does this mean that auto x = static_cast(float) is unsafe?

Yes, for many `float` values.

> 3. what is the proper/safe way of converting float to int then (assuming you want truncation)?

To test if `float` to `int` succeeds, test the limits with carefully constructed `float` values that are exact and incurred no FP rounding in their derivation.  No need for wider types like `double`.

Take advantage `INT_MIN` is a negated power-of-2 and `INT_MAX` is one less than a power-of-2.  Form 2 limits exactly: `INT_MIN_FLT, INT_MAXP1_FLT` (`INT_MAX` plus 1).

With common 32-bit `int`, conversion well specified for float in the -2,147,483,648.999... to +2,147,483,647.999... range, not -2,147,483,648.0 to +2,147,483,647.0.

C-like answer, yet should be realizable in C++.

```
// One more than INT_MAX
#define INT_MAXP1_FLT (static_cast<float>(INT_MAX/2 + 1) * 2.0f)
#define INT_MIN_FLT   (static_cast<float>INT_MIN)
float f;
int i;

// Avoid this as INT_MAXP1_FLT - 1.0f may be inexact
// if (f < INT_MAXP1_FLT && f > INT_MAXP1_FLT - 1.0f) {

if (f < INT_MAXP1_FLT && f - INT_MAXP1_FLT > -1.0f) {
  i = static_cast<int>(f);
else if (f < 0)
  i = INT_MIN;
else if (f > 0)
  i = INT_MAX; 
else 
  i = 0; // NAN case - best to do a isnan(f) test up front.
```

---

This approach works as long as the `xxx_INT < FLT_MAX`.  E.g. we are not dealing with some 128 bit integer type like `uint128_t`.

---

This approach extends well to `double`, `long double` and the various integer types, both signed and unsigned.